# Terminated due to Memory Error when load number of view into UIScrollView

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uiscrollview, out-of-memory

I am using `UIScrollView` in my app that 25 view first time.

user scroll on bottom next 25 view add in scrollview.

I am still entirely not sure this is a memory problem.But i didn't found the code cause of the Memory Problem.

Even I have checked memory leak issue through the instrument tool there is no memory leak.

My code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
        float scrollViewHeight = _scrl_ipad.frame.size.height;
        float scrollContentSizeHeight = _scrl_ipad.contentSize.height;
        float scrollOffset = _scrl_ipad.contentOffset.y;

        if (scrollOffset == 0)
        {

        }
        else if (scrollOffset + scrollViewHeight == scrollContentSizeHeight)
        {
            if (scrl_bottom_reload_view)
            {
                 scrl_bottom_reload_view=nil;
                [scrl_bottom_reload_view release];
            }

            scrl_bottom_reload_view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, scrollContentSizeHeight-100, _scrl_ipad.frame.size.width-20, 60.0)];
            scrl_bottom_reload_view.tag = -50;

            UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((_scrl_ipad.frame.size.width/2)-100, 10, 200, 40)];
            lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:22];
            lbl.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            lbl.text = @"Loading deals...";
            [scrl_bottom_reload_view addSubview:lbl];
            [lbl release];

            UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
            activityIndicator.alpha = 1.0;
            activityIndicator.color = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake((_scrl_ipad.frame.size.width/2)-150, 12, 37, 37);
            activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = NO;
            [scrl_bottom_reload_view addSubview:activityIndicator];
            [activityIndicator startAnimating];


            scrl_bottom_reload_view.hidden = FALSE;
            scrl_bottom_reload_view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            [self.scrl_ipad addSubview:scrl_bottom_reload_view];

            [self performSelector:@selector(LoadScrl) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
        }
}

    -(void)LoadScrl
    {
//called api and fill arrayalldeals arry

        [self func_scrl_ipad];
    }
-(void)func_scrl_ipad
{
        NSArray *viewsToRemove = [_scrl_ipad subviews];
        for (UIView *view in viewsToRemove)
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
            view = nil;
        }

        int temp;
        if([arrayalldeals count] % 2 == 0)
        {
            temp = ([arrayalldeals count] / 2);
        }
        else
        {
            temp = ([arrayalldeals count] / 2) + 1;
        }
        _scrl_ipad.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768,(258*temp)+150);
        _scrl_ipad.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=NO;



        int x = 35;
        int y = 35;
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= [arrayalldeals count]; i++)
        {
            UIView *bgview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 328, 243)];
            bgview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            //bgview.layer.borderWidth = 0;
            //bgview.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
            bgview.tag = i;
            //bgview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            //bgview.layer.borderColor =[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
            //bgview.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
            //bgview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
            //bgview.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0;


            AsyncImageView *imageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 328, 223)];
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
            imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
            imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
            imageView.imageURL =[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@uploads/%@-5.jpg",app.Main_url,[[arrayalldeals objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"deal_id"]]];
            //cell.autoresizesSubviews=YES;
            [bgview addSubview:imageView];
            [imageView release];


            UIView *shadoeview = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,115, 328, 112)];
            CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer greyGradient];
            bgLayer.frame = shadoeview.bounds;
            [shadoeview.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
            shadoeview.alpha = 0.9;
            [bgview addSubview:shadoeview];
            [shadoeview release];

            UIImageView *img_discount = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 57, 57)];
            img_discount.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"discount_tag.png"];
            [bgview addSubview:img_discount];
            [img_discount release];

            UILabel *lbl_disc_text=[[UILabel alloc]init];
            lbl_disc_text.frame=CGRectMake(-2,-10,100,20);
            lbl_disc_text.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            lbl_disc_text.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:14];
            lbl_disc_text.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            int disc = 0;
            if([NSNull null] != [[arrayalldeals objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"value"])
            {
                int main_price = [[[arrayalldeals objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"value"] intValue];
                int disc_price = [[[arrayalldeals objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"price"] intValue];
                int multiply = disc_price *100 /main_price;
                disc = 100 - multiply;
            }
            lbl_disc_text.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"- %d%%",disc];
            [bgview addSubview:lbl_disc_text];
            float degrees = -40; //the value in degrees
            lbl_disc_text.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees * M_PI/180);
            [lbl_disc_text release];

            UILabel *lbl_desc=[[UILabel alloc]init];
            lbl_desc.frame=CGRectMake(8,162, 240, 50);
            lbl_desc.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            lbl_desc.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:16];
            lbl_desc.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            lbl_desc.numberOfLines = 2 ;
            if([NSNull null] != [[arrayalldeals objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"name"])
            {
                lbl_desc.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayalldeals objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"name"]];
            }
            else
            {
                lbl_desc.text=@"";
            }
            [bgview addSubview:lbl_desc];
            [lbl_desc release];

            UILabel *lbl_unprice=[[UILabel alloc]init];
            lbl_unprice.frame=CGRectMake(255,165,60,20);
            lbl_unprice.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            lbl_unprice.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
            lbl_unprice.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            lbl_unprice.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:14];
            if([NSNull null] != [[arrayalldeals objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"value"])
            {
                int unprice = [[[arrayalldeals objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"value"] intValue];
                lbl_unprice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d",unprice];
            }
            else
            {
                lbl_unprice.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$0"];
            }
            [bgview addSubview:lbl_unprice];
            [lbl_unprice release];


            NSString *str_price_line;
            if([NSNull null] != [[arrayalldeals objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"value"])
            {
                int unprice = [[[arrayalldeals objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"value"] intValue];
                str_price_line = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d",unprice];
            }
            else
            {
                str_price_line=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$0"];
            }
            UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:14];
            CGSize size = [(str_price_line ? str_price_line : @"") sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(281, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
            int temp = 60 - size.width;
            UILabel *lbl_line=[[UILabel alloc]init];
            lbl_line.frame=CGRectMake(253+temp,174,size.width+4,2);
            lbl_line.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:252.0/255.0 green:36.0/255.0 blue:148.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            float degre = -20; //the value in degrees
            lbl_line.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degre * M_PI/250);
            [bgview addSubview:lbl_line];
            [lbl_line release];

            UILabel *lbl_price=[[UILabel alloc]init];
            lbl_price.frame=CGRectMake(215,180, 100, 35);
            lbl_price.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
            lbl_price.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            lbl_price.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:24];
            lbl_price.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:93.0/255.0 green:202.0/255.0 blue:242.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            if([NSNull null] != [[arrayalldeals objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"price"])
            {
                int price = [[[arrayalldeals objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"price"] intValue];
                lbl_price.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%d",price];
            }
            else
            {
                lbl_price.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$0"];
            }
            [bgview addSubview:lbl_price];
            [lbl_price release];


            UILabel *lbl_bottom_view=[[UILabel alloc]init];
            lbl_bottom_view.frame=CGRectMake(0,223, 328,20);
            lbl_bottom_view.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
            [bgview addSubview:lbl_bottom_view];
            [lbl_bottom_view release];

            UILabel *lbl_vertical1=[[UILabel alloc]init];
            lbl_vertical1.frame=CGRectMake(100,223,2,20);
            lbl_vertical1.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
            [bgview addSubview:lbl_vertical1];
            [lbl_vertical1 release];

            UILabel *lbl_vertical2=[[UILabel alloc]init];
            lbl_vertical2.frame=CGRectMake(222,223,2,20);
            lbl_vertical2.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];
            [bgview addSubview:lbl_vertical2];
            [lbl_vertical2 release];

            UILabel *lbl_address=[[UILabel alloc]init];
            lbl_address.frame=CGRectMake(4,226, 94, 14);
            lbl_address.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            lbl_address.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            lbl_address.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:12];
            lbl_address.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            if ((NSNull *)app.city_dict == NULL)
            {
                lbl_address.text= @"Vancouver";
            }
            else
            {
                lbl_address.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[app.city_dict objectForKey:@"title"]];
            }
            [bgview addSubview:lbl_address];
            [lbl_address release];


            //LeftTime
            NSString *strDatehere = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayalldeals objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"d_expires"]];
            NSDateFormatter *heredateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [heredateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"]; // set date formate with your dates

            NSDate *datehere = [heredateFormatter dateFromString: strDatehere];
            NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [datehere timeIntervalSinceDate:[NSDate date]];
            [heredateFormatter release];

            double hours = timeDifference / 3600;
            NSInteger remainder = ((NSInteger)timeDifference)% 3600;
            double minutes = remainder / 60;
            double seconds = remainder % 60;

            NSString *strleft_time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0fh, %.0fm, %.0fs",hours,minutes,seconds];

            UILabel *lbl_time=[[UILabel alloc]init];
            lbl_time.frame=CGRectMake(105,226, 110, 14);
            lbl_time.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            lbl_time.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            lbl_time.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:12];
            lbl_time.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            lbl_time.text=strleft_time;
            [bgview addSubview:lbl_time];
            [lbl_time release];

            UILabel *lbl_bought=[[UILabel alloc]init];
            lbl_bought.frame=CGRectMake(222,226, 98, 14);
            lbl_bought.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            lbl_bought.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            lbl_bought.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:12];
            lbl_bought.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            lbl_bought.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Bought",[[arrayalldeals objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"buys"]];
            [bgview addSubview:lbl_bought];
            [lbl_bought release];


            UIButton *btn_scrl=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [btn_scrl setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 328, 243)];
            btn_scrl.tag=i-1;
            [btn_scrl addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_scrl_tag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [bgview addSubview:btn_scrl];


            UIButton *btn_fav=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [btn_fav setFrame:CGRectMake(285,5, 35, 35)];
            if([[[arrayalldeals objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"user_faves"] isEqualToString:@"1"])
            {
                [btn_fav setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"all_deals_fave_pink_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else
            {
                [btn_fav setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"all_deals_fave_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            [btn_fav.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
            if([[[arrayalldeals objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"faves"] isEqualToString:@"0"])
            {
                [btn_fav setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else
            {
                [btn_fav setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrayalldeals objectAtIndex:i-1] objectForKey:@"faves"]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            btn_fav.tag=i-1;
            [btn_fav addTarget:self action:@selector(btn_favorite:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [bgview addSubview:btn_fav];

            [_scrl_ipad addSubview:bgview];
            [bgview release];



            if(i % 2 == 0)
            {
                y = y + 258;
                x = 35;
            }
            else
            {
                x = 399;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

////
now api called more then 10 times i got Terminated due to Memory Pressure Error and App crase

Answer (score 1):

Didn't understand, what are you trying to do? But found many bugs in your code. List out some of them.

1)  In this line, you already set as nil and try to release nil object. This won't release any object, this is main reason for memory leak.

```
       if (scrl_bottom_reload_view)
        {
             scrl_bottom_reload_view=nil;
            [scrl_bottom_reload_view release];
        }
```

2) Try to assign nil to local variable which does nothing.

```
 for (UIView *view in viewsToRemove)
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
        view = nil;
    }
```

3) Where did you release this object.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc].....
```

**Suggestion :**  Above code is more complex, try with Tableview. Use xib to like this job. Otherwise more complex to design as well consume more time to develop.

Comment: but my app support both orientation in ipad how can do ??

Comment: You can easily done with orientation with resize constraint. If you're using more complex UI, load two xib for portrait, landscape.

Comment: but i like app groupon ??

Comment: send me your email id i can send snapshot?

Comment: @BhaveshNai In above case, Instead scrollview, table view is more reliable and ease to work. Use custom table cell to load like above. Reload with two type of custom cell according to orientation.